# If $p$ is a prime and both roots of $x^{2} +px−444p=0$ are integers what is $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If p is a prime and both roots of $x^{2}+px−444p=0$ are integers, what
>   is $p$

I got that for the roots to be integers the discriminant must be a perfect square. Thus, $p(p + 1776)$ must be a perfect square.

However, at this point I am stuck and do not know how to proceed other than trying values for $p$ and checking what works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

We have $\displaystyle q^2=p(p+1776)$ where $q$ is some integer

As $p$ is prime, $\displaystyle  p$ must divde $q,q=pr$(say)

$\displaystyle\implies 1776p=p^2(r^2-1)\iff \frac{1776}p=r^2-1$ which is an integer

Check for the prime factors of $1776$

Comment: I don't follow how you got that 1776p=p^2 * (r^2−1)

Comment: Why does p|x^2 mean p|x only when p is prime? How come when p is not prime this does not hold true?

Comment: @user2612743, for the 1st Question, put $q=pr$ $$\implies (rp)^2=p^2+1776p\iff p^2(r^2-1)=1776p$$$

Comment: @user2612743, for the second if the highest power of prime $p$ that divides $x$ is $h,$ then the highest power of prime $p$ that divides $x$ is $2h$ So, if $p|x^2, 2h\ge1\implies h\ge1$ .But this may not hold if $p$ is not prime. For example, if $8|x^2,$ we can not say $8|x$

Comment: @lab That prime $\,p\mid x^2\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid x\,$ is an immediate consequence of the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, a property which is usually considered a bit more fundamental than the property you mention (that view  comes more to the fore in valuation theory).

Answer (score 3):

Factor it as $(x-a)(x-b)$. Then, $ab=-444p$, so one of $a,b$ is a multiple of $p$. But since $a+b =-p$, they are both multiples of $p$.So $p$ is a divisor of $444$(because $-444p$ would be a multiple of $p^2$)

Answer (score 3):

$ x^2\!+px = 444p\,\Rightarrow \,p\mid x^2\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid x\,\Rightarrow\ p^2\mid 444p\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid 444\,\Rightarrow\, X^2\! + X = 444/p,\ X = x/p,\, $ which has roots $\,m,n\,$ with $\ \color{#C00}{m+n} = -1,\,\ mn = -444/p = \color{#c00}{- 4\cdot 3}\cdot 37/p,\ $ so $\ \color{#c00}{m,n},p \, =\, \ldots$

Comment: How do you know/prove that if p divides x^2 then p also divides x?

Comment: In other words, why does p|x^2 mean p|x only when p is prime? How come when p is not prime this does not hold true?

Comment: @user2612743 That's a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, in particular, *uniqueness* of prime factorizations (or equivalent properties such as Euclid's Lemma).

Answer (score 2):

By [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), the polynomial $x^2 + px - 444p$ is irreducible unless $p^2|444p$.
If both roots of the polynomial are integers, it is not irreducible and hence
$$p^2|444p \;\;\iff\;\; p | 444 \;\;\implies\;\; p = 2, 3 \text{ or } 37$$
So we have only 3 primes to check.

Comment: That would have been my choice too were it not for the algebra-precalc tag (rarely is Eisenstein known at that level). But that's not much of a loss here, since one can make the same deduction elementarily by comparing powers of $p$ in prime factorizations, e.g. as in my answer, or chubakuenko's. But +1 anyhow!